# Conversion failed when converting the varchar to data type int: SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, dapper, dynamicparameters

I am creating a web app in asp.net mvc I have a query which looks like below

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
{
    conn.Open();

    var p = new DynamicParameters();
    p.Add("@SP_RoleId", "7,8,9", dbType: DbType.String, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
    p.Add("@SP_UserId", userId, dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);

    var obj = conn.Query<PendingKmsRequest>(sql: "SELECT [f].[id] AS [FileId],[fvr].[Id] AS [RequestId], [au].[Name]"
                        + ", [fvr].[RequestByUserId], [fvr].[FromDate], [fvr].[ToDate],[f].[Title], [fvr].[Status], [fvr].[StatusRemarks]"
                        + "FROM [dbo].[File] AS[f]"
                        + "INNER JOIN [dbo].[FileViewRequest] AS [fvr] ON [f].[CurrentFileVersionId] = [fvr].[FileVersionId]"
                        + "INNER JOIN [Access].[User] AS [au] ON [fvr].[RequestByUserId] = [au].[Id]"
                        + "WHERE ([fvr].[Status] = 'P' OR ([fvr].[Status] = 'A' AND [fvr].[StatusByUserId] = @SP_UserId AND GETDATE() BETWEEN [fvr].[FromDate] AND [fvr].[ToDate]))"
                        + "AND (SELECT 1 FROM [Access].[UserRoleMap] WHERE UserId=@SP_UserId AND RoleId IN(@SP_RoleId)) = 1", param: p, commandType: CommandType.Text);

    if (obj != null && obj.Count() > 0)
        return obj.ToList();
    else
        return new List<PendingKmsRequest>();
}
```

**NOTE**: Role id is always like (7,8,9) and it is `int` column in the database.

I get this conversion error on this line of code:

```
 WHERE UserId = @SP_UserId AND RoleId IN (@SP_RoleId))
```

This is the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '7,9,10' to data type int.

How can I prevent this error?

Comment: the RoleID as a column is an int, however when your condition contains comma ',' then your condition is a string, not an int.

Comment: Look at the solution [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html)

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: sql server 2008 and I cant use string_split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line in your question code:

```
p.Add("@SP_RoleId", "7,8,9", dbType: DbType.String, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
```

The value `"7,8,9"` is string and parameter type `DbType.String` is string as well.

But, you said this is `int` in your database. This is mismatch.

Further, your query:

```
WHERE UserId = @SP_UserId AND RoleId IN (@SP_RoleId))
```

The query is using `IN` clause.

Dapper can convert your value for `IN` clause if pass in an `IEnumerable`.

Change the line of code as below:

```
p.Add("@SP_RoleId", new[] {7,8,9}, dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use convert string in `array` or any string `split()` function

If you have comma saperated string then you can check it like below steps,

1. If you have `@SP_RoleId = "7, 8, 9"`
2. You can convert this string as below
      `@SP_RoleId = ",7,8,9,"` ( `',' + ltrim(rtrim( @SP_RoleId )) + ','` )
3. Now use `Like` to check `,UserId,`

**Updated code as below**,

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
{
    conn.Open();

    var p = new DynamicParameters();
    p.Add("@SP_RoleId", "7,8,9", dbType: DbType.String, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
    p.Add("@SP_UserId", userId, dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);

    var obj = conn.Query<PendingKmsRequest>(sql: "SELECT [f].[id] AS [FileId],[fvr].[Id] AS [RequestId], [au].[Name]"
                        + ", [fvr].[RequestByUserId], [fvr].[FromDate], [fvr].[ToDate],[f].[Title], [fvr].[Status], [fvr].[StatusRemarks]"
                        + "FROM [dbo].[File] AS[f]"
                        + "INNER JOIN [dbo].[FileViewRequest] AS [fvr] ON [f].[CurrentFileVersionId] = [fvr].[FileVersionId]"
                        + "INNER JOIN [Access].[User] AS [au] ON [fvr].[RequestByUserId] = [au].[Id]"
                        + "WHERE ([fvr].[Status] = 'P' OR ([fvr].[Status] = 'A' AND [fvr].[StatusByUserId] = @SP_UserId AND GETDATE() BETWEEN [fvr].[FromDate] AND [fvr].[ToDate]))"
                        + "AND (SELECT 1 FROM [Access].[UserRoleMap] WHERE ',' +  lTrim(rTrim(@SP_RoleId)) + ',' like '%,' + lTrim(rTrim(UserId) + ',%' " // Updated line
                        + "AND RoleId IN(@SP_RoleId)) = 1", param: p, commandType: CommandType.Text);

    if (obj != null && obj.Count() > 0)
        return obj.ToList();
    else
        return new List<PendingKmsRequest>();
}
```

Comment: if you have `"7,8,9"` as string in `@SP_RoleId` so no need to convert it in array.  You can add commas at start and end of string in query it self and use `Like` to check `,UserID,`. `ltrim()` and  `rtrim()` use to remove extra spaces

Comment: @Ibrahim Shaikh, Answer is updated with description